# How is the id generated for USER_ENTITY and USER_ATTRIBUTE table in Keycloak DB?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am new to the Hibernate, and trying to understand how the Primary Key for USER_ENTITY and USER_ATTRIBUTE is generated.
When I run the Keycloak server in DEBUG mode I could see the ID is being passed to the org.keycloak.models.jpa.entities.UserEntity, but I am unable to find out how the ID is being generated?
Any lead is highly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is a random UUID generated in [`KeycloakModelUtil.generateId()`](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/15.0.0/server-spi-private/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/utils/KeycloakModelUtils.java#L84).
It is called by the [`JpaUserProvider`](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/15.0.0/model/jpa/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/jpa/JpaUserProvider.java).

Comment: Thank you @sventorben, that's exactly I was looking for.